# Is it possible to use more then one AR.ClientTracker in Wikitude SDK?

Tags: javascript, react-native, augmented-reality, wikitude

I'm creating mobile app and using Wikitude SDK to make AR feature.
I want to create a big target collection, but I've read that there is a limitation for number of targets in one collection. It's up to 1000 targets.
But I have 1500 targets, so I desided to split all my targets into 2 collections: 1000 and 500 targets.

The question is how to make search through both collections?

Who knows?

Answer (score 0):

You may only use one AR.ClienTracker at a time.
I highly recommend using [Wikitude's CloudRecognition](http://www.wikitude.com/products/wikitude-cloud-recognition/), which allows you to recognize an almost unlimited amount of target-images.
As a fallback you may categorize your targets and let the user pick the right set of targets to search for on AR-scene start, e.g. Discover "book-covers" or "magazine pages", each of them holding up to 1k of target images for offline use.

In JS you can then define a global AR.ClientTracker and set one of both active. More details to find [in JS API of ClientTracker](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/Reference/JavaScript%20API/index.html).

Please ensure to always use latest [Wikitude AR SDK for Android, iOS, Unity, Xamarin, Titanium, PhoneGap Cordova](http://www.wikitude.com/download/).

Comment: I can't use CloudRecognition because I need to recognize in offline mode. @andreas-fötschl